# while starting nexus service im getting error "Job for nexus.service failed because the control process exited with error code."

Tags: java

nexus.service - LSB: nexus
Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/nexus; generated)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2024-02-26 17:23:39 UTC; 24s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 16011 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/nexus start (code=exited, status=83)
CPU: 28ms

in Linux RHEL9 server I have installed java 8 and installed Nexus but its not starting